# Convert KeyValuePair<int,string> to an int[] array and string[] array

Tags: c#, .net, multidimensional-array, jagged-arrays

```
KeyValuePair<int, string>[][] partitioned = SplitVals(tsRequests.ToArray());
```

Don't worry too much about the method i use; lets just say i get a jagged array of KeyValuePairs that are split equally into different arrays.

```
foreach (KeyValuePair<int, string>[] pair in partitioned)
{
    foreach (KeyValuePair<int, string> k in pair)
    {
    }
}
```

I need to know how i can efficiently get the ints in an int array, and the strings in a seperate string array from the array of keyvaluepairs. That way both of the indexes match eachother in seperate arrays.

For example, after i split it into an int[] array and a string[] array,

```
intarray[3] must match stringarray[3] just like it did in the keyvaluepair.
```

Lets say i have a jagged array with KVP like:

```
    [1][]<1,"dog">, <2,"cat">
    [2][]<3,"mouse">,<4,"horse">,<5,"goat">
    [3][]<6,"cow">
```

I need this to turn into during each iteration

```
    1. 1,2 / "dog","cat"
    2. 3,4,5 / "mouse", "horse", "goat"
    3. 6 / "cow"
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
int[] keys = partitioned.Select(pairs => pairs.Select(pair => pair.Key).ToArray())
    .ToArray();
string[] values = partitioned.Select(pairs => pairs.Select(pair => pair.Value).ToArray())
    .ToArray();
```

Comment: so i wouldnt even need to put this inside the loop?

Comment: Both the `SelectMany` and `Select` method will loop through the sequences provided to them internally, so the loop are happening, you just don't need to write them yourself.

Comment: you did what i want with the KVP, but not what i wanted as a whole.

The first loop needs to happen regardless, its just the second loop i want to avoid. I basically split my keyvalpair arrays into more arrays, but i dont want to put all of them in 2 big lists. I want to put each part in the list every time it loops.

Comment: @Ramie If you don't want two arrays with all of the keys and all of the values then it's not clear what you do want.  Please provide a sample input and output to clarify.

Comment: @Ramie So what you want is two jagged arrays with the keys and values; not flattened.  That's a trivial change; you just need to use `Select` instead of `SelectMany`.

Answer (score 1):

Just to get you started:

```
    var list = new List<KeyValuePair<int, int>>();
    var key = new int[list.Count];
    var values = new int[list.Count];
    for (int i=0; i < list.Count ;i++)
    {
        key[i] = list[i].Key;
        values[i] = list[i].Value;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
List<int> keys = new List<int>();
List<string> values = new List<string>();
foreach (KeyValuePair<int, string>[] pair in partitioned)
{
    foreach (KeyValuePair<int, string> k in pair)
    {
        keys.Add(k.Key);
        values.Add(k.Value);
    }
}
keyArray = keys.ToArray();
valueArray = values.ToArray();
```

Answer (score 0):

```
public static void ToArrays<K,V>(this IEnumerable<KeyValuePair<K,V>> pairs, 
    out K[] keys, out V[] values)
{
   var keyList = new List<K>();
   var valueList = new List<V>();
   foreach (KeyValuePair<K,V> pair in pairs)
   {
      keyList.Add(pair.Key);
      valueList.Add(pair.Value);
   }
   keys = keyList.ToArray();
   values = valueList.ToArray();
}
```

Because you have a jagged array, you also need to flatten it out to use that function:

```
public static IEnumerable<T> flatten(this T[][] items)
{
   foreach(T[] nested in items)
   {
      foreach(T item in nested)
      {
         yield return item;
      }
   }
}
```

Bring it all together like this:

```
 MyKeyValuePairCollection = GetKeyValuePairJaggedArray();
 int[] keys;
 string[] values;
 MyKeyValuePairCollection.flatten().ToArrays(out keys, out values);
```

Comment: Note that he has a jagged array of key value pairs.  That's not an `IEnumerable<KeyValuePair<K,V>>`.  It's a `IEnumerable<IEnumerable>KeyValuePair<K,V>>>`.

Comment: I'd still use the function above, but have additional code to flatten the jaggies first ;)

Comment: My point is that's what you're missing.  You should add that relevant function to flatten the list.

Comment: Curses: the last question I answered was a complicated VB issue, and I had "shared" instead of "static". Fixed that now, as well

Comment: You know that `Flatten` doesn't need to be a custom method, you can just use `SelectMany`.  That's exactly what it does; flatten a sequence of sequences.